# How to select items through code in listboxfor

Tags: html, entity-framework, model-view-controller, listbox, html.listboxfor

I have an Entity Framework/ASP.NET MVC web page.

My .cshtml has this code to populate the list:

```
 <li style="float:left;width:20%;list-style-type: none;">
        <b>List of Users </b><br />
        @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.selectedUsers, Model.ListofUsers, new { style = "width:200px" })
        <br />

 </li>
```

How do I programmatically select or unselect all the items from this list?

I assume if I create the SelectListItem object with the property Selected = true; then the item may be selected.

Let us say if I have a button that has to toggle between selection and unselection - the button can possibly update the list of item objects. But how will it refresh the page?

Comment: I was struggling with the same.. there are always troubles with multiple values when Html.ListBoxFor or DropdownListForm is used.. I decided to create my own html helper or building select from scratch like: ```<select style="width:200px;" name="selectedUsers"> @foreach(var item in Model.ListofUsers){ if(Model.selectedUser != null && Model.selectedUser.Contains(item.Id)) { <option selected="selected" value="@item.Id">@item.UserName</option>}else{<option value="@item.Id">@item.UserName</option>} } </select>``` assuming your selectedUsers property is a int[]

Comment: I did something else. 

I created a partial view. and through a button IAction I iterated through all the members and set their Selection = true; (or false). 

Mine is not a great solution. Something to get by until I find something better. 

Is there an alternative way of using a multiselect listbox instead of using Html.ListBoxFor ?

Comment: Something seems to be missing after *"when the"* (second paragraph).

Comment: I got this working finally. Thanks to you guys

Here in this other thread I have mentioned how I managed to get it running. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070355/checkbox-to-enable-or-disable-a-list-box