# Checkbox to enable or disable a list box

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, checkboxfor, html.listboxfor

I have a checkbox on my ASP.NET MVC page that I create like:

```
<div>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.allUsers, new { Name = "allUsersCheck" })
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.allUsers)
</div>
```

I also have a listbox that I create with:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.selectedUsers, Model.ListofUsers, new { style = "width:200px", size = 10, Id = "lbUsers" })
```

I have this following script (which I wrote to disable the listbox when my checkbox is checked. I can't understand why it doesn’t work. Can someone point out what's wrong in my code please?

This script is in the same .cshtml page and not in the .js file:

```
<script >

    $(function () {
        $('#allUsersCheck').click(function () {
            $('#lbUsers').prop("disabled", $(this).prop('checked'));
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the Id selector of '#allUsersCheck'. The checkbox does not have an Id attribute unlike your list box(?).

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.allUsers, new { Name = "allUsersCheck" })
```

Try the following with an Id attribute:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.allUsers, new { Name = "allUsersCheck", Id = "allUsersCheck" })
```

Comment: Actually it didnt work. I tried like you said, and also by removing the Name attribute. Neither worked.

Comment: No messages.. but neither did it enable or disable the listbox.
it compiled and ran without errors. 

And just to be sure, where would these errors be shown ? not in the browser I could see

Comment: How lame
I had to include something like this
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

and it works after that. thanks.

Comment: I also had to use id instead of Id

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Took me a while to figure out the entire list of things I need to do.

Here's all I did to finally get it working.

1. Firstly, I needed this jquery library being used.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

2. Then I had to create a function under the above jquery inclusion

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#allUsersCheck").change(function () {
            $("#lbUsers").find("option").prop("selected", this.checked)

        });
    });
</script>
```

In the above you'll see allUsersCheck is the checkbox element's id and lbUsers is the id for the ListBoxFor element.

3. The next thing is, in my .cshtml I needed to use/create the listboxfor / checkbox elements. This is how I did it

```
      <b>Users </b><br />
      @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.selectedUsers, Model.ListofUsers, new { style = "width:200px", size = 10, id = "lbUsers" })
      <br />


      <div>
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.allUsers, new { id = "allUsersCheck" })
           @Html.LabelFor(m => m.allUsers)
      </div>
```

I also used a bool flag as part of my model. allUsers is the flag. The bool flag was needed for something else in the controller code and not for UI reasons.

I am not sure if this is the best method. But this is the method I could get it working.

Thanks to the guys who helped me in this process get this working. Obviously not without them.